# How to create a two dimensional array from a stream in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a text file like this:

**ids.txt**

```
1000
999
745
123
...
```

I want to read this file and load it in a two dimensional array. I expect to have an array similar to the one below:

```
Object[][] data = new Object[][] { //
     { new Integer(1000) }, //
     { new Integer(999) }, //
     { new Integer(745) }, //
     { new Integer(123) }, //
     ...
};
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
File idsFile = ... ;
try (Stream<String> idsStream = Files.lines(idsFile.toPath(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)) {
    Object[][] ids = idsStream
       .filter(s -> s.trim().length() > 0)
       .toArray(size -> new Object[size][]);

    // Process ids array here...
}
```

When running this code, an exception is raised:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: null
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.stream.SpinedBuffer.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.stream.Nodes$SpinedNodeBuilder.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.stream.SpinedBuffer.asArray(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.stream.Nodes$SpinedNodeBuilder.asArray(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
...
```

How can resolve this exception?

Comment: Why `new Integer(1000)`? And you want an `[][]` where the inner array always has `length == 1`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider The ids are passed to a third party library that accept only `Object[][]` as input.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Given a `Stream<String>` you can parse each item to an `int` and wrap it into an `Object[]` using:

```
 strings
        .filter(s -> s.trim().length() > 0)
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .map(i -> new Object[]{i})
```

Now to turn that result into a `Object[][]` you can simply do:

```
Object[][] result = strings
        .filter(s -> s.trim().length() > 0)
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .map(i -> new Object[]{i})
        .toArray(Object[][]::new);
```

For the input:

```
final Stream<String> strings = Stream.of("1000", "999", "745", "123");
```

Output:

```
[[1000], [999], [745], [123]]
```

Comment: If you suspect that strings may sporadically have spaces before and after, then it's better to add the separate `trim` step: `strings.map(String::trim).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())`. Also I would use `Integer::valueOf` instead of `Integer::parseInt` as it matches better the wanted type (`Integer`, not `int`). Though probably that's a matter of taste.

Comment: @TagirValeev Why is it "better to add the separate trim step" ?

Comment: @Stephan: this way you can parse files which have spaces after numbers (like `"1  \n2\n3  \n"`). Currently you will have `NumberFormatException` on such files.

Comment: Do you think there is a benefit in these two `map` operations instead of simply saying `.map(s -> new Object[]{Integer.parseInt(s)})`?

Comment: @Holger don't know really. I like to split each logical transformation into a separate `map` step - I think it makes to code more readable. I suppose it's just a matter of personal preference - I doubt there's much of a performance impact.

Answer (score 5):

Your last line should probably be `size -> new Object[size]`, but you would need to provide arrays of Integers of size one and you would also need to parse the strings into Integers.

I suggest the following:

```
try (Stream<String> idsStream = Files.lines(idsFile.toPath(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)) {
    Object[][] ids = idsStream
       .map(String::trim)
       .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
       .map(Integer::valueOf)
       .map(i -> new Integer[] { i })
       .toArray(Object[][]::new);

    // Process ids array here...
}
```